Runbook grouped data adding count to the df
enter image description hereNew to all this however I'm doing a little project and am trying to create a runbook to drop data from a delta table and then group and add the count.
This is what I have gotten to so far see image:
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

(df
.groupBy(F.col('Fuel'))
.agg(F.count('Fuel').alias('FuelCount'))
.show())

delta_table_path = "Tables/dimvehiclefuel" 
data = spark.range(5,10) 
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(delta_table_path)

however when saving it will only save the top table and not this:
+--------+---------+
|    Fuel|FuelCount|
+--------+---------+
|  Hybrid|      224|
|  Diesel|      250|
|Electric|      246|
|Gasoline|      280|
+--------+---------+



Fuel
FuelCount




Hybrid
224


Diesel
250


Electric
246


Gasoline
280



Is there any way to get this saved exactly as is in to a table to then use in PowerBI?
Many thanks in advance
I've tried the groupBy function but this simply returns an error

If you are new to programming, it's important to understand that some functions can make changes to the objects passed into them "in place" and others, much more commonly, do not; where instead they "return" the object transformed. You can check the documentation when working with functions to see if they have a return and what that return is.
When you do df.groupby() you can see in documentation returns GroupedData.
That GroupedData is then passed into .agg() which you can see in documentation returns a "Series or Dataframe"
That Dataframe returned is the one you are looking for, but you pass it right to show() where it's displayd on the screen and then just... lost, as show() doesn't return anything nor does it edit the dataframe passed to it in-place; and it would be kind of an odd choice if it did return or edit in-place, right?
Instead you want to remove the Show() and catch the return of that function call chain into a variable and then use that new variable and the dataframe in it to write out your table:
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

groupedDF = df.groupBy(F.col('Fuel')).agg(F.count('Fuel').alias('FuelCount')).show()

delta_table_path = "Tables/dimvehiclefuel" 
data = spark.range(5,10) 
groupedDF.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(delta_table_path)

If you are still wanting to see the dataframe after it's grouped, you can just add a groupedDF.show() line after creating the groupedDF
